# SQL Server One Way Data Synchronization

Tags: sql-server, ssis, synchronization

I have 2 SQL Server Databases A and B, and I want to synchronize (continuously, every 10 minutes, max) the data from 70-80% percent of the tables from A to B (just A -> B, B is a read only database), but with some constraints:

- The schemas of the tables will 99% the same - tables from database B will have and extra **DeletedDateTime** column. This means that deleting an entry from a table in database A should result in a soft delete in that same table in database B.
- There some transformations might be needed on some cells before moving the data: like changing the reference system of some latitude and longitude values
- Any change in database A should be reflected in database B in 5 - 10 minutes
- I have to use SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition, so features like "Change data capture" aren't available. Upgrading to Enterprise edition or using a newer version of SQL server isn't an option unfortunately.

Now, I've thought of possible ways of doing this, but given that SQL Server isn't really my area of expertise, I'm looking for some suggestions:

1. Use SQL Server Change Tracker along side SSIS. This seems like it's doable.
2. Any commercial products that would do this pretty much out of the box? Red Gate, ApexSQL, etc.?
3. Custom .NET implementation with Windows Services - this one I don't really want to do.
4. Any other suggestions?

This doesn't sound like such an exotic scenario and I'm pretty sure someone has done it before.

I'm just looking to be pointed in the right direction :)

Thank you

Comment: SSIS for moving data + [Change Tracking](https://littlekendra.com/2010/06/23/cdcvsct/) to select rows that changes

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'm not sure why this is mentioned "It is recommended to use snapshot isolation with Change Tracking!". This means that whenever I do CUD operations on a table with Change Tracking enable, I need to run in Snapshot Isolation?

Comment: It is recommended [Work with Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/work-with-change-tracking-sql-server) `Change tracking has been designed to work well with snapshot isolation. Snapshot isolation must be enabled for the database. All the steps that are required to obtain changes must be included inside a snapshot transaction. This will ensure that all changes that are made to data while obtaining changes will not be visible to the queries inside the snapshot transaction.` But you could take alternative approaches.

Comment: Oh, ok. Use snapshot when reading from the change table, not when doing regular CUD operations on a table, right?

Comment: How many tables, what sizes are the tables, how often are they changed?

Comment: Probably 30 tables (give or take), some of them will be pretty big, in terms of number of rows, in the millions. They will be changed fairly often, as part of day to day operations.